# Need Laptop to show same "Desktop" as Desktop computer

Tags: windows-10

I do the same work from my "desktop computer" and my laptop.  I have onedrive account.  How do I get my laptop's desktop to show the same as my "desktop computer"?   Thanks!

Comment: You don't say which OS... Assuming Windows, just login with the same Microsoft account on both.

Comment: Please add the work that you have performed in an attempt to solve your own issue. Have you tried a Google or Bing search? What were the results of this query? Have you reviewed any OneDrive documentation in an attempt to resolve your issue?

Comment: "show the same"… same what? Same theme & background picture? Same icons, apps & documents?

Answer (score 2):

You should read at least a little bit the user manual in order to get a glimpse of the *Microsoft* *Windows* *OneDrive* Cloud File Service Provider.

You might be referring to the *Desktop View*, but that is not the only thing that is replicated by *OneDrive*.

You should at least check out the following settings:

[Replication Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7ysm.png)

Among other things, these settings are ensuring the fact that the *Desktop View* is the same on all of your electronic devices. Still this will be true for all of your static electronic devices running the *Microsoft* *Windows* Operating System. For your mobile electronic devices running the *Google* *Android* operating system, for instance, this will be different. Things have gotten very complicated nowadays.

[BackUp Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGoZM.png)

These settings are ensuring the fact that the *Desktop View* will be fully replicated. More than that, they are enforcing the backup procedures of your *Desktop*, of your *Documents*, and of your *Pictures*.

[Personal Vault Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYQBp.png)

You will also have the chance to set up a Personal Vault for securing your sensitive pieces of information among your electronic devices.